# Longest word from a given list of letters

Tags: prolog

Given a list of letters I'm trying to found the longest word that can be made with those letters.

```
include('words.pl').

word_letters(Word, Letters) :- atom_chars(Word, Letters).

cover([],_).
cover([Head1|Tail1], List2) :- select(Head1,List2, List3), cover(Tail1, List3).

solution(ListLetters, Word, Length) :- word(Word), 
                                       word_letters(Word,LettersWord), 
                                       length(LettersWord, Length), 
                                       cover(LettersWord,ListLetters). 

topsolution(Letters, Word, LMax) :- solution(Letters, Word, LMax).
topsolution(Letters, Word, LMax) :- select(_, Letters, RemainingLetters), 
                                    topsolution(RemainingLetters, Word, LMax).
```

The word_letters predicate transforms a given word in a list of letters.
The cover predicate tells if a given list is included in the second list.

```
?-cover([a,b,c], [b, a, a, c])
true
```

The solution predicate finds for a given list of letters all the words that can be made with those letters and their length.

My problem is with the topsolution predicate which should return just the solutions with the biggest length, but instead it works just like solution.

Can you please help me understand how can I make the topsolution so that it will output just the words with the maximum length?

Here is my words database: tinyurl.com/prolog-words

Comment: Do you just need to do `once(topsolution(...))`?

Comment: It doesn't start with the longest word.

Comment: You mean `:- include('words.pl').`?

Comment: Unfortunately, `topsolution/3` as you've defined it simply doesn't add anything to what `solution/3` does. Thanks to `cover/2`, `solution/3` already tries excluding all the permutations. What you'll need to do in `topsolution/3` is obtain a list of results from `solution/3` and find the longest. Probably using `findall/3` or `setof/3` or `bagof/3`.

Comment: I solved my problem using another predicate.

    `topsolution(Letters, Word, Lmax) :- length(Letters, N1), 
                                                            topsolutionCount(Letters, Word, Lmax, N1).`

    `topsolutionCount(_, _,_,0).`
    `topsolutionCount(Letters, Word, N, N) :- solution(Letters, Word, N).` `topsolutionCount(Letters, Word,Lmax, N) :- N1 is N-1, topsolutionCount(Letters, Word, Lmax, N1).`

Comment: Please consider submitting it as a solution and accepting it so others can benefit from your work!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using another predicate.

```
topsolution(Letters, Word, Lmax) :- length(Letters, N1), 
                                    topsolutionCount(Letters, Word, Lmax, N1). 
topsolutionCount(_, _,_,0). 
topsolutionCount(Letters, Word, N, N) :- solution(Letters, Word, N). 
topsolutionCount(Letters, Word,Lmax, N) :- N1 is N-1, 
topsolutionCount(Letters, Word, Lmax, N1).
```